# Donot want the array to display simultaneously in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an array example. There is a text box that accepts the number and on clicking on add, it adds the number to a defined array. And on display i want it to display the array. But what is happening is, as soon as i click on add button, the number simultaneously is being displayed on the HTML page. I guess its because of ng-model, but i want it to be displayed only when i click on display button. Please help.

```
<html  ng-app="Swabhav.Array">
 <head>
<title>Array</title>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="arraynumber">
    <button type="button"  value="Add"  ng-
      click="addElementToArray(arraynumber)">Add</button>
    <button type="button"  value="Display" ng-
        click="displayElementsInArray()">Display</button>
    <li ng-repeat="element in elements track by $index ">
       <h4> {{element}} </h4> 

    </li>

    </div>

    <script>

         angular.module("Swabhav.Array",[])
                .controller("ArrayController",
       ["$scope","$log",function($scope,$log){

                      $scope.numbers=[];
                      $scope.number="";

                      $scope.addElementToArray=function(number){
                          $scope.numbers.push(number);
                          $log.log("inside add "+ $scope.numbers)
                      }
                       $scope.elements=[];
                      $scope.displayElementsInArray=function(){
                          $log.log("Inside Display")
                          $scope.elements.push($scope.numbers);
                      }
                }])
    </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the below code, also check this working [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/1FWczBJwY9NVnBN87aQ3?p=preview) for your example scenario.

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.numbers=[];
  $scope.elements=[];
  $scope.addElementToArray=function(number){
      $scope.numbers.push(number);
      $scope.arraynumber='';
  };
  $scope.displayElementsInArray=function(){
      angular.extend($scope.elements, $scope.numbers)
  };
```